# How could Proca equation be written in NP formalism

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, cosmology

I am trying to do some calculation of fields in curved background. Is there anyone know the complete form of Proca equation 
$$\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}+m^{2}A^{\nu}=0$$and$$F_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\nabla_{\nu}A_{\mu}$$
in Newman-Penrose formalism.

In this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00893117 it gives the NP Proca equation in Schwarzschild background so some spin coefficients vanishes. Is there a complete form of NP Proca equation?

Comment: Have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02565).

Comment: Thanks, I mean the form together with both project componet A and EM scalar \Phi.

Comment: The appendix in the paper I mentioned has the equation in a generic spacetime, not just in pp-wave.

Comment: Indeed, however, it is a second order pde and the orginal equation is of order one. the approach is making it much more complex.